# JavaScript influxes query

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to connect to an influx Db using javascript, specifically node.js, but I get the following error:

> node:14356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:14356) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

The code I am using is below:

```
const Influx = require(‘influx’);
const express = require(‘express’);
const path = require(‘path’);
const os = require(‘os’);
const bodyParser = require(‘body-parser’);
const app = express();
const influx = new Influx.InfluxDB(‘http://user:pass@datas:8086/db’);
    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
    
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, ‘public’)));
app.set(‘port’, 3000);
    
influx.getMeasurements()
   .then(names => console.log(‘My measurement names are: ’ + names.join(’, ')))
   .then(() => {
      app.listen(app.get(‘port’), () => {
         console.log(Listening on ${app.get('port')}.);
      });
   })
   .catch(error => console.log({ error }));
    
app.get(’/api/v1/usage’, (request, response) => {
   influx.query(SELECT mean(*) FROM \"operatingsystem\" WHERE \"environment\" = \"ENV\" AND time >= (now() - 1m) GROUP BY time(1m), \"component\" fill(none) host = ${Influx.escape.stringLit(os.hostname())})
    .then(result => response.status(200).json(result))
    .catch(error => response.status(500).json({ error }));
});
```

In essence, at this point, I just want to be able to query the influx Db and get the JSON response back. Can anyone advise on this?

Thanks

Lee.

Comment: why not do what the warning message suggests, and `.catch()` all of your promise chains, and examine what the actual error is?

Comment: Hey, thanks, I thought that is what the code was doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for anyone else that encounters this, the issue was with my query, I lifted some of this code from the influxDb tutorials, and it appears that I negleted to fix the influx query I was making to EXCLUDE the following:

```
host = ${Influx.escape.stringLit(os.hostname())})
```

This needed to be removed as my query did not require this. Once I done this, it worked perfectly. My fault for not reading things as thoroughly as I should have! We live and learn though....

Answer (score 1):

*** This is NOT an answer ***

---

A throwed error is not getting catched.

Add the following code and look which error you are letting go through :

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

It will help to debug and find the real problem.

Comment: Gregory NEUT thanks, where should I add this, anywhere?

Comment: Yes anywhere, it have to be executed tho

Comment: seems to be:UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

Comment: My bet is that `influx.query` returns a [IResult](https://node-influx.github.io/class/src/doc.js~IResults.html) object which cannot be `stringified`. To be sure about it replace [influx.query](https://node-influx.github.io/class/src/index.js~InfluxDB.html#instance-method-query) by [influx.queryRaw](https://node-influx.github.io/class/src/index.js~InfluxDB.html#instance-method-queryRaw)

Comment: Hey, thanks, I did that, still seem to be getting the same issue, (node:5688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (c:\nodeJSCode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1119:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (c:\nodeJSCode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at influx.queryRaw.then.catch.error (c:\nodeJSCode\connectToInflux.js:35:44)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)

Comment: Ok then instead of doing `response.status(200).json(result)`, do `response.status(200).json(Object.keys(result))` you i'll see what kind of data you are dealing with